# InputStream from relative path

Tags: java, path, io, inputstream, relative-path

I have a **relative file path** (for example "/res/example.xls") and I would like to get an **InputStream** Object of that file from that path.

I checked the `JavaDoc` and did not find a constructor or method to get such an InputStream from a path/

Anyone has any idea? Please let me know!

Comment: Thats not a relative path. That's an absolute path.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/res/example.xls");
```

But never read from raw file input stream as this is terribly slow. Wrap it with buffering decorator first:

```
new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

BTW leading slash means that the path is **absolute**, not relative.

Answer (score 97):

```
InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Path);
```

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: Consider using buffered version for better efficiency: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path))

Answer (score 4):

Initialize a variable like: `Path filePath`, and then:

```
FileInputStream fileStream;
try {
    fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath.toFile());
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Done !
Using Path you can have access to many useful methods.

Comment: The existing answers already covers the question in a more simple way.

Answer (score 4):

Found this to be more elegant and less typing.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/test/resources/sampleFile.csv"));
```

Note: In my case, file was very small (used for Unit Tests), but prefer to use BufferedInputStream for better efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

`new FileInputStream("your_relative_path")` will be relative to the current working directory.