# Getting nullpointerexception while reading file from resource folder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, sbt, intellij-14

I am getting `NullpointerException` when I try to read the file present in `src/main/resources` location. It occurs when I run in `jar` format. But when I compile the code and run it , its running fine in `Intellij`.

Note: I am using sbt package to build the jar and running it.

Please help out. thanks!

Comment: Post your code. Otherwise, we're just guessing as to what the program might be doing.

Comment: configFileName = CustomParams.dbName + "_" + CustomParams.tableName + "_config.conf"
    println("configFileName "+configFileName)
    //check in resource and get the path of it
    //println("ssdfs  " +Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.getResource(s"/$configFileName").getFile)
    val filePath = DqDriver.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(s"$configFileName").getFile

Comment: Edit your question to include the code, please.

Comment: thanks for your time. I got the solution from another suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that have been packed into the JAR are not accessible from the file system anymore. This can be seen when looking at the `URL` returned from `myClass.getResource("file.txt")`, e.g.:

```
/home/sria/cde-spark-assembly-1.0.jar!/file.txt
```

Note the `!` denoting that the file is packaged into the JAR.

---

This means you always have to access resource files using the following pattern:

For a file in `src/main/resources/file.txt`:

```
myClass.getResourceAsStream("file.txt")
```

---

There is two reasons why you might not want to do that:

1. Adding files to the resources directory will increase the JAR file size.
2. The file cannot be accessed using standard file system operations.

---

As an alternative you can load the file from a (configurable) path in the file system, using for example:

```
val inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myPath))
```

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692298/inputstream-from-relative-path))

This way you can load a file, e.g. relative to the [JAR file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) or the [execution directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939556/how-to-get-the-execution-directory-path-in-java).

---

I hope this helps.

*Note:* Both `sbt package` and `sbt assembly` will package resource files into the JAR.

Comment: I tried running with assembly too. I am getting the path like this /home/sria/cde-spark-assembly-1.0.jar!/config.conf .  there is an exclamatory coming from no where.

Comment: @A srinivas that's correct. This path denotes that the given file is packed into the JAR. It cannot be treated as a normal file, and should be retrieved using `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: thanks.. its working fine now. but do you know any alternative for fat jar, as its not effective to transfer the fat jar from local to remote everytime?

Comment: @Asrinivas I adapted my answer accordingly.